# Wordpress Grid PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, grid, blogs

I have an issue with adding a Grid Layout to my Projects here is the code:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'projects',
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
        );
        $q    = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-6">
                <h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And its Looks like this: [The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Pzx.png). It's simply repeats the 2-column Grid as many time as I have posts.

Can anyone help me to fix this, to get a normal Grid layout for my projects?

Thanks!

Comment: should it be single row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` from top and `<?php endwhile; ?>` from bottom. Because you have a custom WP query inside that loop. So no need of default Wordpress post query loop there.

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new here.